blender 4.2 курсор всегда на объекте
как привязать 3D курсор чтобы он перемещался вместе с объектом и оставался в его центре? надоело каждый раз shift+s, 2 нажимать


А зачем? Если вы хотите выполнять операции относительно центра объекта, то вместо того, чтобы дёргать 3D-курсор, лучше просто переключите Pivot Point, наверное?
